# Is there a position where the weaker side can force stalemating the stronger side?

Tags: endgame, draw, stalemate

Usually, the (materially) stronger side stalemates the materially weaker side. Is there a position where the weaker side can forcibly stalemate the stronger side?

The only position I know where this happens is not forced, as White can choose to lose the pawn or go for the repetition instead.

```
[Title "White to move"]
[FEN "K7/P1k5/8/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: To clarify, you're asking for a position where a side that is down material (1 pawn or more) can force a stalemate?

Comment: If the weaker side can force a draw, he's not really the weaker side, is he?  That is, forced draws have an engine evaluation of 0.0.

Comment: updated the question. I indeed mean material, not engine evaluation or other positional factors.

Comment: There are several examples in the answer to this question: https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/23671/9025

Comment: @Herb thanks. I found this interesting. However in all examples the stalemating side is the stronger one (except in one case where both sides are equally strong)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[FEN "8/8/8/3p4/1ppp4/prrp1K2/nqpp4/nbbk4 w - - 0 1"]

1. Kf2
```

Comment: I think an absurd solution is the only way to answer this question.

Comment: I like this solution. Black has plenty of extra material. Why do you think absurd solutions are the only answer? Do you think that there are no "normal" positions that could be from a real game resulting in a forced stalemate by the materially weaker side?

Comment: I think it's the best way to illustrate that the question has an obvious answer (and the answer is yes, there does exist a position [...]).

Comment: Actually, there even exists a study where White gets a draw by either stalemating Black or getting stalemated, but don't nail me on it, I don't remember anything else...

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Oh no! Now you have triggered my interest!!

Comment: @Hauptideal: https://en.chessbase.com/post/study-of-the-month-alexander-petrovich-kazantsev-a-life-between-science-fiction-and-science-fiction contains several studies; Nr. 2 is a double stalemate. THX to the article author for notifying me.

Comment: Can even arrange the black units in a 4x4 square! E.g. pppp/rrpp/nqpp/nbbk takes only 14 captures of white units